# can anyone send me good example for TTMessageController

Tags: iphone, ios4

can anyone send me good example for TTMessageController.

Answer (score 0):

After some research it seems like using MFMailComposeViewController is a much better choice.  It is from the MessageUI framework from the official SDK.